# Scraping from a slippery .aspx page

Tags: web-scraping

I need some values that I can see on a web page pop-up but the source is unknown al least with my knowledge.

The page is: https://www.afpmodelo.cl/AFP/Indicadores/Valor-Cuota.aspx

and the data appears in Modal (or something like that) after clicking the "DESCARGAR EXCEL" button.

[image]

I have searched the source, and the network XHR using Chrome dev tools, but data is nowhere to be found.

I use ruby with Mechanize for scraping, but suspect that's not the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is showing in the web tools for me. Right click > Inspect:

[image]

The following code fetches that (slippery) table:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'https://www.afpmodelo.cl/AFP/Indicadores/Valor-Cuota.aspx'

mechanize = Mechanize.new { |agent| 
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}

mechanize.get(url).form_with(:id => 'form1') do |form|
    # submit the form using the DESCARGAR EXCEL button
    data_page = form.submit(form.button_with(:id => 'ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_GRILLA'))

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(data_page.body)
    results_table = doc.css('div.modal-dialog table')

    # do something with the results_table
    puts results_table
end
```

Comment: It wasn't slippery at all, you have it wright. Guess I was kind of blind. Advice to my future self:`if stuck_ligth_at_night? got_to_sleep end`

Comment: Glad it helped!